# How to change how Google routes to my home address

Tags: google-maps

I just bought a new home and there are multiple streets to take while driving to my house. Now, one of the three ways is probably 1 minute faster but has really bad roads and also neighbourhood is also not very safe. I would strongly prefer that anyone driving to my house should not use that route.

Is there any way for me to control how Google Maps routes to my home? I personally feel like I should have a say in what street my family members and friends take while coming to my house/ Not Google.

Is there any way to change this?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can always report your findings to Google (also you can try to lie to Google and report them fake directions)

- open **https://www.google.com/maps**
- click **Directions**
- enter the starting point and destination for the route for which your directions were wrong
- on the left, click on a route description for step-by-step directions
- in the bottom right of the map, click **Send feedback**

**Google Maps uses information from two places to choose a route:**

- **anonymous data from your phone/device:** if **`location data collection`** is turned on, your phone will send bits of anonymous data to Google. This shows your location and helps Google pinpoint situation. Google Maps uses this information to give you the best route and estimate travel times. Travel times, among other sources, are made by using location data from the past and present
- **partners:** traffic and incident data is licensed to Google from partners like governments, non-profits, schools, and businesses

**Google Maps gets information to update the map from two sources:**

- **people who use maps:** people who use Google Maps can let us know when they find problems
- **partners:** map data is licensed to Google from partners like governments, non-profits, schools, and businesses